# how to disable all the minor modes (when a specific major mode is enabled) with elisp

Tags: minor-mode

Is there any function do disable all the minor modes if I enable a specific major mode (let's take the `text-mode` as an example)?

Comment: Enabling a major mode normally begins by disabling all buffer-local minor modes.  So please be more specific.

Comment: I am guessing that you only want to disable the *buffer-local* minor modes (and not the global minor modes).  To my knowledge Emacs does not provide a convenient way to identify an active mode as either buffer-local or global, but you could likely use `(buffer-local-variables &optional BUFFER)` and check each of the `minor-mode-list` values against that list. Note that *globalized* modes act in `after-change-major-mode-hook` so you can't simply disable minor modes in the major mode hook, as that will be too early.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a function like this:

```
(defun disable-all-minor-modes ()
  (interactive)
  (mapc
   (lambda (mode-symbol)
     (when (functionp mode-symbol)
       ;; some symbols are functions which aren't normal mode functions
       (ignore-errors 
         (funcall mode-symbol -1))))
   minor-mode-list))
```

Note that this will probably disable more functionality than you think.

If you want to disable minor modes when you in a specific mode, you can just hook this function like this:

```
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook #'disable-all-minor-modes)
```

Simply replace `lisp-mode` with the major mode you want to use, and keep in mind that this will run in derived major modes as well.

Comment: Disabling modes in the major mode hook is too early.  Globalized minor modes enable their buffer-local mode in `after-change-major-mode-hook`, which runs later.  You can instead use the major mode hook to `(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'FUNC :append :local)`

Comment: I haven't thought about that. Thanks, @phils.

Comment: This function can disable some modes globally.